# Vuejs: listen to props changes and use it

Tags: vuejs2, watch, vue-props

I am developing a project using Vue JS and I need to watch the props changes and call it inside a `<span>`.

I have used `watch()` and it shows that the props values are assigned.

[image: I have added a screenshot]

But when I call it inside the `<span>` the value is not showing.

```
props: ['verifyText', 'verifyValue', 'profileId', 'logged', 'verifyType', 'status'],
    watch: {
        verifyText: function () { // watch it
            this.verify_text = this.verifyText;
        },
        verifyValue: function () {
            this.verify_value = this.verifyValue;
        },
        verifyType: function () {
            this.verify_type = this.verifyType;
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            verify_type: this.verifyType,
            verify_text: this.verifyText,
            verify_value: this.verifyValue,
        }

    },

//using inside span
<span>{{verify_text}}</span>
```

Comment: Are you using Vuex?

Comment: yes. I am using Vuex

Comment: At first glance it looks like it should work. What value are you seeing inside the `<span>`? Is the problem that it doesn't update or does it just not render anything at all? e.g. If you initially set `verify_text` inside `data` to some dummy value do you see that rendered? It's also unclear why exactly you are copying the props to `data` properties instead of just using the props directly. e.g. `{{ verifyText }}`. Copying props to `data` with a `watch` is usually a sign of an underlying design flaw.

Comment: Yes. I used it as `{{ verifyText }}` but it does not work. Thats why I tried to assign to another variable to check if it is assigning.
When I initially set a value for `verify_text`, it shows in the vue. But when the prop value changed, it does not get the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receive and insert new data that changes from 'watch'

Try this.

```js
props: ['verifyText', 'verifyValue', 'profileId', 'logged', 'verifyType', 'status'],
watch: {
   verifyText: function (new_value) {
       this.verify_text = new_value;
   }
},
data() {
   return {
      verify_text: this.verifyText,
   }
},
//using inside span
<span>{{verify_text}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by watching the verify_text in the parent component.

```
'verify_text': function (value) {
    this.verify_text = value;
  },
```

Same for the verify_type and verify_value
Thank you all for replying.